# How to force redraw of soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I created a custom keyboard which doesn't resize correctly when the orientation changes.  I've tried `invalidateKeys()`, and manually setting the size of all of the keys, but no joy.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a simular problem with resizing my keyboardview's key height dynamically.  To workaround the problem I did a couple of things:

1) Create a new class that extends the Keyboard class that defines a public getKeyHeight method and overrides the getHeight method.  My prototype code:

```
public void setKeyHeight(int height) {
   super.setKeyHeight(height);
}

@Override
public int getHeight() {
   return getKeyHeight() * 3;
}
```

2) Defined a new method in my

```
double height_modifier = 1.5;

int height = 0;
for(Keyboard.Key key : mKeyboard.getKeys()) {
   key.height *= height_modifier;
   key.y *= height_modifier;
   height = key.height;
}
mKeyboard.setKeyHeight(height);
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: If it extends the Keyboard class, then what does your constructor look like?

Comment: The new method seems to be able to change the key height successfully, but how do I change the overall keyboard height?

Comment: Can you explain the code to override getHeight() and return getKeyHeight() * 3? I couldn't figure out what is that for. Without putting it the keyboard height is totally wrong, after putting it it is better but there's a slight gap in the bottom. I changed it to times 2 and the keyboard height is exactly right! However this makes my bottom row key untouchable.. seems like something invisible is blocking it and I cannot press the bottom row keys but I have no idea why..

Answer (score 0):

My keyboard changes some keys and redraws the softkeyboard after the user hits any character button. I call the `invalidateAllKeys()` on my Subclass of `KeyboardView` to redraw the keyboard. `invalidateAllKeys()` works fine!