# How to get height of keyboard when activity created in android

Tags: android, listview, keyboard

I want to auto display a listview with same height of keyboard of device when user goes to that particular activity. For this, I am calling three methods that are, showKeyboard(), getKeyboardHeight() and then hideKeyboard() and then giving height to that listview and showing that listview. But the problem is once I call showKeyboard(), calculate height and then hideKeyboard(), the keyboard doesn't hide and remains visible. Also I'm getting height as 0. I cannot display that listView. Is there any another process to get height of keyboard or any correction in below code ? See the code below :

**showKeyboard() method -**

```
private void showKeyboard() {
             InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             keyboard.showSoftInput(editChatBox, 0);
        }
```

**getKeyboardHeight() method -**

```
public int getKeyboardHeight() {
          final View rootview = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
           linearChatLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        Rect r = new Rect();
                        rootview.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                        int screenHeight = rootview.getRootView().getHeight();
                        int newHeight = screenHeight - (r.bottom - r.top);
                        if (newHeight > heightOfKeyboard) {
                            heightOfKeyboard = screenHeight
                                    - (r.bottom - r.top);
                            // heightOfKeyboard = heightDiff;
                        }

                        Log.d("Keyboard Size", "Size: " + heightOfKeyboard);
                    }
                });
        return heightOfKeyboard;
    }
```

**hideKeyboard() method -**

```
private void hidekeyBoard() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editChatBox.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

**Inside onCreate() method -**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_new_layout);

   ArrayAdapter<String> chatQueAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            R.layout.chat_que_row, R.id.textChatQue, queArrays);
    myListView.setAdapter(chatQueAdapter);

        showKeyboard();
        heightOfKeyboard = getKeyboardHeight();
        hidekeyBoard();
        myListView.getLayoutParams().height = heightOfKeyboard;
        myListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: You can't get keyboard height before its first opening. For the first time you can use default value (for example 230dp) and then adjust the value. And set windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize.

Comment: @gabber but i'm opening keyboard using showKeyboard() method and then calculating height and hiding it using hideKeyboard() method. I'm getting zero height and keyboard remains open.

Comment: to be able to calculate the size in such a way, you need  set windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize

Comment: @gabber i tried that too..but still not working.

Comment: getKeyboardHeight is wrong. You must adding global observer in onCreate mehod. After keyboard is shown you can check heightOfKeyboard.

Comment: Refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204325/how-to-force-redraw-of-soft-keyboard/9695482#9695482

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added global layout on root view and I was able to resize list view to same size as Keyboard.

The Pink Box is the resized ListView . I have tested this sample app on 2 Samsung devices and it work fine on Both.

[image]

Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity class

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.fet.minebeta.R;

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private int heightDiff;
    private ListView myListView;
    private EditText editChatBox;

    private boolean wasOpened;
    private final int DefaultKeyboardDP = 100;
    // Lollipop includes button bar in the root. Add height of button bar (48dp) to maxDiff
    private final int EstimatedKeyboardDP = DefaultKeyboardDP + (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? 48 : 0);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        editChatBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);

        //Listen for keyboard height change
        setKeyboardListener();

//        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//        editChatBox.requestFocus();
//        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(editChatBox, 0);
//
//        if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
//            inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
//        }
//
//        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
//                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
//        );
    }


    public final void setKeyboardListener() {

        final View activityRootView = ((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            private final Rect r = new Rect();

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Convert the dp to pixels.
                int estimatedKeyboardHeight = (int) TypedValue
                        .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, EstimatedKeyboardDP, activityRootView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                // Conclude whether the keyboard is shown or not.
                activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                boolean isShown = heightDiff >= estimatedKeyboardHeight;

                if (isShown == wasOpened) {
                    Log.d("Keyboard state", "Ignoring global layout change...");
                    return;
                }

                wasOpened = isShown;

                if (isShown) {

                    //Set listview height
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = heightDiff;
                    myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    myListView.requestLayout();
                    myListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "KeyBoard Open with height " + heightDiff +
                            "\n List View Height " + myListView.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Again this is just quick demo you can enhance things according to your need.

Comment: I tried your solution. I am getting height of keyboard but only when I click on edittext that let keyboard open. I was trying to open keyboard manually and then assigning that height to listView without using editText. That's y I wrote showKeyboard() method. Is it possible without editText click?

Answer (score 2):

Use OnGlobalLayoutListener for getting Keyboard height or implement above code snippet

chatRootLayout is your xml root layout
pass this rootLayout as parentLayout parameter in checkKeyboardHeight

```
    private void checkKeyboardHeight(final View parentLayout)
{
  chatRootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
  {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() 
        {
                Rect r = new Rect();

                chatRootLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                int screenHeight = chatRootLayout.getRootView().getHeight();
                int keyboardHeight = screenHeight - (r.bottom);

                if (previousHeightDiffrence - keyboardHeight > 50) 
                {                           
                    // Do some stuff here
                }

                previousHeightDiffrence = keyboardHeight;
                if (keyboardHeight> 100) 
                {
                    isKeyBoardVisible = true;
                    changeKeyboardHeight(keyboardHeight);
                } 
                else
                {
                    isKeyBoardVisible = false;
                }
            }
    });
}
```

keyboardHeight() Method :-

```
   private void changeKeyboardHeight(int height) 
{
    if (height > 100) 
    {
            keyboardHeight = height;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, keyboardHeight);
            yourLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no perfect solution that will work all the time. I have seen many people use `ViewTreeObserver` to get the keyboard height, although this would not work sometimes, it's better than nothing. [Try it out](https://www.google.com.hk/#safe=strict&hl=zh-CN&q=android+get+keyboardheight).

I wrote a Input Method Editor a few years ago. As I remember, there is no function called "getCurrentHeight" exposed from the IME classes. So don't go this way.

And please note that nowadays many IME support to change keyboard height at runtime(when it's shown on screen), maybe you would have to take this into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this KeyBoard this app has given the usuage with using RelativeLayout onSize changed https://github.com/w446108264/XhsEmoticonsKeyboard

Answer (score 0):

i have figured out height by using custom pass then calculate it

```
private int keyboardHeight;

// passed here 230dp
final float popUpheight = getResources().getDimension(
            R.dimen.keyboard_height);
    changeKeyboardHeight((int) popUpheight);

// call this where you want height of keyboard
checkKeyboardHeight();

int previousHeightDiffrence = 0;

private void checkKeyboardHeight() {

    rootlayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    rootlayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                    int screenHeight = rootlayout.getRootView()
                            .getHeight();
                    int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom);

                    if (Math.abs(previousHeightDiffrence - heightDifference) > 50) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        imageEmoji
                                .setImageResource(R.drawable.emoji_btn_normal);
                    }

                    previousHeightDiffrence = heightDifference;
                    if (heightDifference > 100) {
                        isKeyBoardVisible = true;
                        changeKeyboardHeight(heightDifference);
                    } else {
                        isKeyBoardVisible = false;
                    }

                }
            });
}


/**
 * change height of emoticons keyboard according to height of actual
 * keyboard
 *
 * @param height minimum height by which we can make sure actual keyboard is
 *               open or not
 */
private void changeKeyboardHeight(int height) {

    if (height > 100) {
        keyboardHeight = height;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, keyboardHeight);
        emoticonsCover.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

}
```

for more details checkout from [here](https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/xmppsample/ActivityChatScreen.java),
Hope this help you